# Convert golang struct to proto

Tags: go, struct, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I'm doing a request validation in my api gateway using golang validator from the struct.

```
type User struct {
    DigitalId string `json:"digital_id" validate="required,len=16"`
    Role string `json:"role" validate:"required,oneof=customer seller superuser"`
}
```

After parsing request payload and validating the contents, I want to transform the data into a proto instance to send it over to a grpc API. Is there a fast way to do this in golang?

I tried to initiate a new proto message instance and assign all values one by one. I'm just wondering if there's a shortcut / nicer way of doing this since the keys on the struct and on proto are exactly the same.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the traditional way is the other way around: you declare a proto schema and generate struct from it, which you then can marshal/unmarshal.

Comment: IIUC you'd want to add annotations e.g. `validate="required,len=16"` to structs in protoc-generated subs? You cannot. The structs generated by protoc should be considered final and it is good practice to map between these and what could be similar (!) structs in your code. The generated stubs also include private fields that won't be on your structs (`state`,`sizeCache`,`unknownFields`). There's no "sugar" to do this mapping for you; you'll need to write the mappings.